# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () Ошибка при возврате json объекта со scope session

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, сессия

Это делаю в первый раз, так что скорее всего явно где-то ошибся. Помогите пожалуйста. Пишу приложение на java, Spring, jQuery(ajax). Делаю корзину и дали задание класть данные о заказе в сессию. Есть класс Basket поля которого подходят для корзины, имеет одну связь one-to-many и одну many-to-one, конфигурация в spring(м.б. неверно):

```
  <bean id="basket" class="com.Basket" scope="session">
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
  </bean>
```

когда делаю запрос возвращает ошибку Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () при этом  в console рисует нужный json:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/basket',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset = utf-8',
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
```

в контроллере:

```
@Autowired
public Basket basket;

@RequestMapping(value="/basket", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Basket getBasket() {
        ...
        return basket;
    }
```

Если возвращаю любой другой объект то код работает как надо. Возможно проблема в самой конфигурации, как правильно класть в сессию в таких случаях или может быть ошибка в другом, буду рад любой помощи.

Ошибка в браузере: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`

В логах:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
```

Классы POJO:

```
public class Basket {
    private int id;
    ...
    private User user; //many-to-one
    private List<Toys> toys; //one-to-many
    }

public class User{
    private int id;
   ...
   private List<Basket>baskets;
}

public class Toys{
    private int id;
    ...
    private Basket basket;
}
```

Comment: Приложи ошибку из логов

Comment: Приложи структуру класса `Basket` а также всех классов полей внутри него, если они не являются частью стандартной библиотеки. Судя по ошибке, у тебя бесконечная рекурсия из-за циклической ссылки.

Comment: добавил, сеттеры и геттеры идут стандартно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя есть явные циклические зависимости между указанными бинами. `Basket` хранит в себе `User`, а `User` хранит в себе `Basket`. Такая же ситуация с `Toys` и `Basket`. Тебе стоит **перепроектировать** иерархию связей. Или же, можно сделать подсказать Jackson'у, что некоторые поля не стоит сериализовать (тут надо учесть момент, что их не будет в результатирующем JSON) при помощи [JsonIgnore](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) примерно так:

```
public class Basket {
    private int id;
    ...
    private User user; //many-to-one
    private List<Toys> toys; //one-to-many
    }

public class User{
    private int id;
   ...
    @JsonIgnore
   private List<Basket>baskets;
}

public class Toys{
    private int id;
    ...
    @JsonIgnore
    private Basket basket;
}
```

Есть и [другие способы](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) в виде разного рода умных ссылок и т.д., но я рекомендую именно избавиться от циклических связей